# Windiws 8 search for contact by phone number

Tags: windows, windows-8

I know how to use the ContactPicker to pick a contact from the people app and get the contact details, but I do not know how to search for a contact and get the contact details by a phone number for example.

Anybody has some sample JavaScript code?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any way to search or iterate through the contacts.  You could open the Search charm and seed it with the phone number you want to search for using [SearchPane.Show()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br225096.aspx), but it does not seem like the People app searches by phone number.  It also seems like you cannot get phone number data from the hotmail SDK for contacts.

Comment: Is there an API I need it for the following scenario. I have a listview with some phone numbers and I want to show contact names and photos of those numbers instead the numbers. Is there a way to do that ?